# Wikipedia Api - Category images

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

I got a problem. When query find subcategories, js get error.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
    at Object.success (load.js:21)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLScriptElement.b.onload.b.onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:4)"
```

In my opinion the problem is when find Titles: Category: (random name) or better SUBCATEGORY. There is a way for ignore it? And possible take images without error?

Im creating viewer category Wikipedia prime ministery of italian with API Wikipedia.

```
function getImages(pageid,title){
  $.ajax  ({ //caricamento dinamico
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php",
      data: {
        format: "json",
        action: "query",
        prop:"pageimages",
        titles:title,
        pithumbsize:300,
        redirects:"1" // utilizzato nel caso il termine inserito non sia specifico, viene così effettuato il redirezionamento
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      async: false,
      success: function (data)
      {
      if (data.error){
        alert(data.error.info);
        return false;
      }
      console.log(data);
      var src=data.query.pages[pageid].thumbnail.source;
      return src;
      console.log(data.query.pages[pageid].thumbnail);

    }
  });
}

function renderPage(title, contentImage){
  var newChild = document.createElement("div");
  newChild.className = "item"; //<div class="item"></div> aggiunge la classe al tag div creato in precedenza
  newChild.innerHTML = title; //<div class="item">playerName</div> aggiunge il contenuto di playername all'intenro del tag
  newChild.style.dysplay="none";
  var src=contentImage;
  console.log(src);
  newChild.style.backgroundImage='url('+src+')';
  playersContainer.appendChild(newChild);
}

function firstCallAPI(){
    $.ajax  ({ //caricamento dinamico
        url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", //in questa prima chiamata si prende tutto il testo dalla pagina di wikipedia e si da una formattazione
        data: {
          format: "json",
          action: "query",
          generator:"links",
          cmtitle: "Category:Prime_Ministers_of_Italy",
          list:"categorymembers",
          redirects:"1", // utilizzato nel caso il termine inserito non sia specifico, viene così effettuato il redirezionamento
          cmlimit:500
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data)
        {
        if (data.error){
          alert(data.error.info);
          return false;
        }
        var res= data.query.categorymembers;
        var contentImages = new Array();
        var arrayIdpages = new Array();

        for(var x=0; x < res.length; x++){ //creo un dizionario e una lista per ordinare le immagini in ordine cronologico (ordine per idPages)
            pageid=res[x].pageid;
            var src = getImages(pageid,res[x].title);
            dizImage = {'idpage':pageid, 'contentImages': src, 'title': res[x].title}
            contentImages.push(dizImage);
            arrayIdpages.push(pageid);
        }
        arrayIdpages.sort();

        for (var i = 0; i < arrayIdpages.length; i++) {
          renderPage(arrayIdpages[i].title, arrayIdpages[i].contentImages)

        }
          }
        });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is being thrown at the line `var src=data.query.pages[pageid].thumbnail.source;`, and the error is telling you that the property `source` does not exist on the `data.query.pages[pageid].thumbnail` object. I would suggest removing that line and the `return src` line as it's preventing your second `console.log` from firing - which might help you diagnose the issue further.

Comment: Yes of course, now work. But i dont take image from category.. how can i take image by pageid and API Wikipedia for category. :(